# Radius of Convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{a}{k}(z)^k$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

How would I find the radius of convergence for this for complex $z$?
$$(1+z)^a = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{a}{k}z^k$$ around $z=0$

I am guessing that it is 1 but not sure how to prove yes or no.
Also, is there a difference between LHS / RHS? Would the RHS follow only if certain criteria are met for the LHS?

Comment: Typo? n should be k?  For integer a, finite sum.

Comment: In terms of a, it doesn't have to be integer, it can be a complex exponent. In this case then $(1+z)^a$ becomes multivalued, but for this problem would that matter in terms of finding the radius of convergence?

Comment: If the binomial coefficients are non-zero, the ratio test works.

Comment: Examine $\binom{a}{k}$ as $k\to \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use the ratio test then $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \left\vert\frac{\binom{a}{k+1}z^{k+1}}{\binom{a}{k}z^k}\right\vert = |z|\lim_{k\to \infty} \left\vert \frac{(a-k)!k!}{(a-k-1)!(k+1)!}\right \vert = |z|\lim_{k\to \infty} \left\vert \frac{a-k}{k+1}\right \vert =|z|\lim_{k\to \infty} \left\vert \frac{a}{k+1} - \frac{k}{k+1}\right \vert = |z|$$ so the series converges if $|z| < 1$. Hence the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: With the proviso that $a$ is not a positive integer - otherwise the sum is finite, and the radius infinte.

Comment: Yes that is true. I was assuming $a$ has a non zero imaginary component since that is the non trivial case